# How to get get-volume output in % and how to check used RAM in % in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ram, volume

I have tried using `Get-volume` to output to a file and it works great.

Is there any way to get result in **%** and is there a way to show **used ram**?

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the `free disk space` by yourself like:

```
Get-Volume | Select-Object -Property *, @{name="FreeSpace"; expression={ "$(100 / $_.Size * $_.SizeRemaining)%" }}
```

Use `Get-Ciminstance Win32_OperatingSystem` to get information about the `Operating System` like `RAM usage`:

```
$osData = Get-Ciminstance Win32_OperatingSystem
$osData.FreePhysicalMemory
$osData.TotalVisibleMemorySize
```

Comment: Better: `'{0:p2}' -f ($_.SizeRemaining / $_.Size)`

Comment: Anyway to do it with out get-ciminstance?